# Crystal Reports Looks for x86 log4net.dll on x64 machine

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have an Any Cpu .NET Web Application which runs with Crystal Reports. My problem is when I install this app to a x64 machine and install crystal reports runtime for x64, it doesn't work: "log4net.dll not found" error although I have log4net.dll in assembly folder. When I install x86 runtime it works but since my MSSQL Server is based on x64, it gives database logon failed error.

How is it possible for an Any Cpu application to look for x86 log4net.dll on an x64 machine? How can I fix this?

Comment: "but since my MSSQL Server is based on x64 it gives database logon failed error" that doesn't make sense, 32 bit app can access x64 Server just fine, it shouldn't even care about it.

Comment: @Martheen thank you for your reply. That was the only reason I could think of. Why do you think it may happen? I installed the same any cpu app to 3 machines none of them had this issue. Only this one has this issue and only difference between them is the "log4net.dll". This one uses 32 bit log4net others use 64 bit log4net.

Comment: Can you verify that in the machine where the database logon failed error, the connection string is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you design an app with the Any CPU parameter the app will require both the 32 bit and 64 bit assembly libraries to be installed, as well as both the 32 bit and 64 bit crystal report runtimes.

If you want a 64 bit app that only uses the 64 bit assembly and runtime, you should set the cpu required to x64.